# Objects will not appear in the java applet when drawn. How am I supposed to properly use the paint/repaint methods in AWT?

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint

I have an applet interface that is supposed to draw a ball on the screen and have it bounce off the edges when the run button is pressed. There are other functions, but they require this first one to work. When run is pressed currently, nothing happens. I don't think I am correctly drawing the object right. I have put in `System.err.println()` statements around, and checking the console the program does go to the right methods when the button is clicked. I just dont know what is wrong with the methods that should be drawing the object.

The code is almost 500 lines, but i'll paste it in this body if need be. Here it is: http://ideone.com/JL0B2

Comment: Every time you draw the object, you have to return control to the event dispatch thread (EDT) for the program to actually draw it on the screen and process other events.

Comment: @PaulTomblin Ok. I don't have anything running in threads as its written. Is the EDT automatically created/handled by AWT or do I have to instantiate it manually somewhere, or is there a statement I can use to give control back to it?

Comment: *"How am I supposed to properly use the paint/repaint methods in AWT?"*  1) Jump into the time machine and return to the last millennium when people could remember it..  -- While I'm here.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: How are you compiling your classes? Are you using Eclipse or the command line?

Comment: @ilango compiled in Jcreator, and run in a simple web page

Comment: @AndrewThompson Funny how the webpage for SSCCE is a massive wall of text. Not very short or simple.

Comment: *"Funny how the webpage for SSCCE is a massive wall of text. Not very short.."*  A short question might have a long answer.  There is really no connection between the length of the document and the technique it aims to teach.  ..Funny how people asking for free help from others seem unwilling to read a document that makes all our lives easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to override paint of `drawingpanel`: this is where you draw your circle. Currently the circle appears only when you press Run button because it's painted over the components.
During normal painting, the applet area is painted (this is where your current `paint` works), and the all the components you added are painted, over the already painted dot.

At the start of your program `dot` is `null`, so paint can't correctly draw it - it throws NullPointerException.

You don't have to "cache" the Graphics instance: always use the Graphics that is given to you in paint.

If you want the circle to move, you have to create another thread so that it updates the values and then schedules repaint of the `drawingpanel`.
And you don't have to repaint the entire applet, just the `drawingpanel`.

If you still need help, ask them in comments.

**Edit:**

Here's your `drawingpanel` where the dot is painted:

```
    Panel drawingpanel = new Panel() {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            if (dot == null) {
                return;
            }
            g.drawOval(dot.leftOf(), dot.topOf(), dot.widthOf(), dot.heightOf());
            g.fillOval(dot.leftOf(), dot.topOf(), dot.widthOf(), dot.heightOf());
        };
    };
```

And your `Bounce` applet does not override `paint()` method.

To implement animation, add [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface to the `implements` section.
Add another field:

```
    volatile boolean running = false;
    private Thread animationThread;
```

Now let's implement simple animation:

```
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            if (!showtails) {
                dot.setColor(drawingpanel.getBackground());
            }
            update();// check if speed, size, or shape changed
            draw();// draw next dot based on move(), or initial condition
            pause();
            move();// calculate and prepare the coordinates for the next
                   // iteration to be drawn
        }
    }

    public void draw() {
        drawingpanel.repaint();
    }

    public void pause() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void move() {
        dot.left--;
        dot.top--;
    }
```

And the final detail is the action handler:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();

        if (source == this.runbutton) {
            running = !running;
            if (animationThread == null) {
                animationThread = new Thread(this); 
            }

            if (running) {
                dot = new CircDot(100, 100, sizebar.getValue(), Color.RED);
                animationThread.start();
            }
        } else
            ...
    }
```

Here's how it works. Your implementation started `run()` in the action handler and didn't return the control back to the EDT, thus your application appeared hung: it stopped handling messages.

Now when Run button is clicked, the state field `running` is inversed, then a new thread is created if it wasn't already and started. The thread executes `run()` method. So the actions in the `while` body are executed until `running` becomes `false`.

- draw method call `repaint()` on the `drawingpanel` which schedules a paint operation.  When the message queue is empty, the system will call its `paint` method to re-draw the panel.
- pause method calls `Thread.sleep(500)` to stop execution for 500 milliseconds. The less the number is, the faster the dot will move. The value here will depend somehow on speed. *Never implement a pause with loop*: you just waste processor time for no gain and you can't predict how much time it will take.
- move just decreases `top` and `left` coordinates of dot so that it moves to the left top corner of the window.

It is worth noting that `running` is declared `volatile` because the field is accessed from multiple threads without other means of synchronization. If it's not there, the running animation may not see its modification from the EDT in the action handler.

Comment: Ok, so if i go in order to see if i understand this correctly:

Nothing shows up because the circle is drawn, and then everything is placed on top of it. I should be drawing right on to `drawingpanel` instead, yes?

Wouldn't the intial condition of null be irrelevent, since the paramaters are specified when the `runbutton` is pressed? Or is it just better to draw the first dot from the get go?

For the last 3 points you made, I'm just not sure how to implement them, but I do understand what you are saying.

Comment: Yes, the circle is drawn on the applet window. Then the applet contains child windows which are painted above it. /* If it were Swing components and JApplet, you wouldn't have seen anything but your dot (when it's not null) in the applet window. */

Comment: No, painting is done even if you didn't click Run. So your paint method should not throw NullPointerException, see the added check for null. Your clear method can be implemented by nullifying the dot field, and calling repaint: nothing is painted. It's up to you if the dot is drawn right away or hidden until Run is clicked, your program should not throw Exception when it operates correctly.

Comment: I've updated my answer with simple animation using Thread. Another way to do it is to use Timer.